# laravel 5.2 signup probleme

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm working on laravel 5.2  shopping cart site and i have this sign up problem  when i put an email address and a password to signup it tells me that password is required. but i filed the password place
[the view signup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pvZo.png)

this is my user controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserController extends Controller
{
   public function getSignup(){
       return view('user.signup');
   }
    public function postSignup(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request,['email'=>'email|required|unique:users',
        'password'=>'required|min:4',
        ]);
        $user=new User([
            'email'=> $request->input('email'),
            'password'=>bcrypt($request->input('password'))
        ]);
        $user->save();
        return redirect()->route('product.index');
    }
    public function getSignin(){
        return view('user.signin');
    }
    public function postSignin(Request $request){
        if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request->input('email'), 'password'=>$request->input('password')])){
            return redirect()->route('user.profile');
        }
    return redirect()->back();
    }
    public function getProfile(){
        return view('user.profile');
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to `print $request->input('password'); exit; ` at first line of `postSignup()` function. And let me know what it print.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post the view?, check if in the view you are putting to the password input the same name you are trying to get in the controller action

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently see that you have in your view password input name capitalized, and in the controller you are trying to get the input value using the name in lowercase, that was the problem, pretty common to everyone, don't feel bad about it.

Answer (score 0):

this is the view of signup controller

```html
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
            <h1>Sign Up</h1>
            @if(count($errors)>0)
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <div class="alert alert-danger form-group">
                        <p>{{$error}}</p>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            @endif
            <form action="{{route('user.signup')}}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                    <input type="email"id="email" name="email" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
                {{csrf_field()}}
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```